# Is there any code using apply to optimize this?

Tags: r, apply, data-manipulation

### Load library

```
library(engsoccerdata)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

### Extract Liverpool data from England league data

```
england$Date <- ymd(england$Date)
Liverpool.home <- england %>% filter(Date > '2001-08-01', home == 'Liverpool')
Liverpool.away <- england %>% filter(Date > '2001-08-01', visitor == 'Liverpool')
```

### Make variable points

```
Liverpool.home$points = 0

for(i in 1:nrow(Liverpool.home)){

  if(Liverpool.home[i,]$result == 'H'){
    Liverpool.home[i,]$points = 3
  }
  else if(Liverpool.home[i,]$result == 'D'){
    Liverpool.home[i,]$points = 1
  }

}
```

I know How to use apply function is really bored and common question in stackoverflow, however I cannot solve this problem using apply function.
Is there any method? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dplyr**

The function `case_when` ("a vectorised set of if and else ifs") from `dplyr` equivalent of the SQL CASE WHEN statement. We need to use `.$` inside `mutate.`

```
library(dplyr)
Liverpool.home %>% 
  mutate(points = case_when(.$result == 'H' ~ 3,
                            .$result == 'D' ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ 0))
```

**sqldf**

The CASE WHEN statement in SQL from `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
df <- sqldf('SELECT result, 
                     CASE WHEN result = "H" THEN 3 
                          WHEN result = "D" THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                     END AS points
             FROM [Liverpool.home]')
head(df)
```

Output:

```
  result points
1      A      0
2      A      0
3      H      3
4      D      1
5      H      3
6      H      3
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to recode one of your columns with character type to a column of integers. One of the options is simply using an `ifelse` which is vectorized and convenient to use in this case, and you don't want to use `apply` which is meant to loop through `matrix`:

```
Liverpool.home$points <- with(Liverpool.home, ifelse(result == "H", 3, 
                                                     ifelse(result == "D", 1, 0)))

head(Liverpool.home[c("result", "points")])

#  result points
#1      A      0
#2      A      0
#3      H      3
#4      D      1
#5      H      3
#6      H      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
transform(Liverpool.home, points = 3 * (result == "H") + (result == "D"))
```